# Test JsonUtils in GWTTestCase

Tags: gwt, native-methods, gwttestcase

I want to create some testcase to see if my JSON parsing classes work correct. Therefore I want to instantiate them with a JavaScript object which I create form a JSON String throw the JsonUtils.

My problem now is that, JsonUtils is a native method, so there is now source code available for it, during testing.

Is there a possibility to built GwtTestCases which include native methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after writting the question I got some new ideas to google and found this article: [UnsatisfiedLinkError in GWTTestCase. Options](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/f6cd9f09009049fc).

So apperently you just cant use native methods in the GWTTestCase constructur, but you can use them inside the test function.

Example illeagal:

```
JSWidgetBasic jswb;
public JSWidgetBasicTest() {
    String s_jswb = "{\"zzzz\":\"type\"}";
    jswb = JsonUtils.safeEval(s_jswb).cast();
}

public void testWidgetType() {
    assert (jswb.getZZZZ().compareTo("type") == 0);
}
```

but this is allowed

```
public JSWidgetBasicTest() {
}

public void testWidgetType() {
    String s_jswb = "{\"zzzz\":\"type\"}";
    JSWidgetBasic jswb = JsonUtils.safeEval(s_jswb).cast();

    assert (jswb.getZZZZ().compareTo("type") == 0);
}
```

Hope this helps someboedy, cause I wasted a few hours finding it....